# Search special keywords with elasticsearch

Tags: go, elasticsearch

I using the elasticsearch to use search the key word on my app by go. However, when i  text the keyword is 'not', it return result is null, it not act searching with 'not'. I use the type "phrase_prefix" for filed name.
Thank you!

I try to find the special keywords in elasticsearch query but not found.

Comment: Try searching for `"not"`, not `not`

Comment: I try it but still return null

Comment: Could you please provide index mapping ? this is happen because you have configured `stopword` filter for your field and it removing stopwords.

Comment: qsMulti:=elasticQuery.NewBoolQuery().Must(elasticQuery.NewMultiMatchQuery(search, "name",).Type("phrase_prefix"))

Comment: I using this query.
  searchResultEvent, errEs := els.Search().
   Index(index).
   Query(query).
   From(0).
   Size(countIndex).
   TrackTotalHits(true).
   Pretty(true).
   Sort(sort, eventType).
   Do(context.Background())